# Firebase Cloud Functions - Outbound networking - Problem

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have several Cloud Functions. I don't do any external requests. But in "Functions/Helth/Outbound networking" I see some usage of each of my functions. What does it mean? Why?

I'm using GeoFire query inside one of my Cloud Functions. Can it be related to External network?

Why I have usage of "Outbound networking"? Because of this external library GeoFire?

Comment: GeoFire runs on the clients, so can not be causing outbound traffic from your Cloud Functions. Aside from that, look into [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the changes that we can help you find the cause of this traffic.

Comment: Thank you, bus the thing is I'm trying to use it on the server side in the Cloud Function.

Comment: OK. I guess it might be technically possible; it just seems like a recipe for problems since GeoFire depends on keeping an active listener, which doesn't match well with Cloud Functions' run time requirements. That said: it'll be impossible for us to say what's going with without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: if you **don't** use GeoFire, do you also get the outbound traffic?